# Powershell, xml and xmlrpc

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-rpc

So, I'm writing a script to do some simple xmlrpc requests. As far as I can tell Powershell doesn't have anything built in, so the best and simplest solution I've found is to simply create the xml and post it using invoke-webrequest or invoke-restmethod.

If someone knows of a better way with out of the box functionality, feel free to educate me.

Now, here's the part I'm having some trouble with. Generating the xml. How I would like it to work:
create a custom object, add properties, convert to xml and post. Even better would be to create an xml-object, add nodes and properties and then post it.

This appears to be a bit of a PITA though, and at this point I feel it will be easier to treat the xml as a string in Powershell and edit/manage it that way. So, am I missing something or is working with xml in Powershell not as easy as I had hoped?

Edit: To clarify, I'm asking for the best tool/technique to create custom xml in Powershell. So far my impression is that the best way is to simply build it as a string, as using the built in xml tools is cumbersume and messy. However I realize this would not be viable for larger or more complex XML-structures.

What I have so far, which doesn't work and isn't as pretty as I'd like.
This code gives me the following error

***Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'Appendchild'.***

```
$xmlreq = [xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
<methodName>methodname</methodName>
</methodCall>
'@

$child = $xmlreq.CreateElement("params")
$xmlreq.methodCall.Appendchild($child)
$child = $xmlreq.CreateElement("param")
$xmlreq.methodCall.params.Appendchild($child)
$child = $xmlreq.CreateElement("value")
$xmlreq.methodCall.params.param.Appendchild($child)
$child = $xmlreq.CreateElement("string")
$xmlreq.methodCall.params.param.value.Appendchild($child)
$xmlreq.methodCall.params.param.value.string = "value"
```

What the resulting XML should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
<methodName>methodname</methodName>
<params>
<param>
<value>
<string>param1</string>
</value>
</param>
<param>
<value>
<string>param2</string>
</value>
</param>
<param>
<value>
<string>param3</string>
</value>
</param>
<param>
<value>
<string>param4</string>
</value>
</param>
<param>
<value>
<struct>
<member>
<name>property1</name>
<value>
<int>0</int>
</value>
</member>
<member>
<name>property2</name>
<value>
<string>value</string>
</value>
</member>
<member>
<name>property3</name>
<value>
<int>1</int>
</value>
</member>
<member>
<name>property4</name>
<value>
<string>value</string>
</value>
</member>
<member>
<name>property5</name>
<value>
<int>2</int>
</value>
</member>
</struct>
</value>
</param>
</params>
</methodCall>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is there an error? Is the XML not coming out the way that you like?

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and ***include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output***. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: Additionally, there are XMLRPC implementations for Powershell (for example https://github.com/mosserlee/PSClient-for-XML-RPC) and for .NET that you might integrate into your script. Try to use something that already exists instead of rolling your own implementation.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll try to clarify: My main question right now is what is the best way to create and edit and xml-file in powershell? The reasons for not using an existing implementation of XML-RPC are two-fold, first 'm using it as an excercise to learn and second I prefer my solutions to be small, portable and not rely on components that are not included in the operating system.

Comment: So, after looking at the code in the project you posted I see that they do indeed treat the xml as a string rather than using Powershell's built in XML-parsing. which leads me to believe that at least I'm not the only one who finds the way Powershell interacts with XML to be a bit lacking.

Comment: can this be done on Linux, or just Windows?  .NET versus .NET Core to my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this to build your tree:

```
[xml]$doc = @'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
<methodName>methodname</methodName>
</methodCall>
'@

$node1 = $doc.CreateElement('params')
$node2 = $doc.CreateElement('param')
$node3 = $doc.CreateElement('value')
$node4 = $doc.CreateElement('string')

$node4.set_innertext('param1')
$node3.AppendChild($node4)
$node2.AppendChild($node3)
$node1.AppendChild($node2)

$node2 = $doc.CreateElement('param')
$node3 = $doc.CreateElement('value')
$node4 = $doc.CreateElement('string')

$node4.set_innertext('param2')
$node3.AppendChild($node4)
$node2.AppendChild($node3)

$node1.AppendChild($node2)

$doc.methodCall.AppendChild($node1)

$doc.Save("$(pwd)\foo.xml")
cat .\foo.xml
```

This is just a quick and dirty example to demonstrate a point. You'll need to polish this up for your needs. I did the following:

- Move the `xml` type declaration to the variable and not the string.
- Built the tree first then added it to the document

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much :) I think I see how it works now, and I think I can build on it to get what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

XLinq with some helper functions makes it relatively easy to build XML documents in PowerShell. For example:

```
function xdoc ($nodes) { [system.xml.linq.xdocument]::new( [System.Xml.Linq.XDeclaration]::new("1.0", "utf8", ""), [object[]] $nodes) }

function xe ($name, $value, $rest) { [xml.linq.xelement]::new($name, $value) }

function param ($p) {xe param $(xe value $(xe string $p))}

$d = xdoc $(
    xe methodcall $(
        xe methodname methodname
        xe params $(
            param param1
            param param2
            param param3
            param param4
            xe param $(
                xe value $(
                    xe struct $(
                        xe int 0
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```